# Not able to solve. and getting this error

Tags: python-3.x, sum, range, nameerror

I was trying to solve this python exercise:-

Question: 
Given a range of first 10 numbers, Iterate from start number to the end number and print the sum of the current number and previous number

My code(1):-

```
rng = range(10)
def sum_of_numbers(x) :
    for i in x :
        b = i + (i-1)

        if i in x :
            return b
        elif b < 0 : # when number will be negative.
            return i

print("current number is"+ str(i) + ". And sum of the previ. and curr. number is " + str(sum_of_numbers(rng)))
```

But I am getting this error : -

```
File ".\question2.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("current number is"+ str(i) + ". And sum of the previ. and curr. number is " + str(sum_of_numbers(rng)))
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

---

then I tried modifying it
Code 2:

```
rng = range(10)
def sum_of_numbers(x) :
    if i in x :
        b = i + (i-1)
        return b
    elif b < 0 :
        return i

print("current number is"+ str(i) + ". And sum of the previ. and curr. number is " + str(sum_of_numbers(rng)))
```

same error in terminal:-

```
File ".\question2.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("current number is"+ str(i) + ". And sum of the previ. and curr. number is " + str(sum_of_numbers(rng)))
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Comment: you define `i` inside your function, but use it outside. Other from that, you are not takting the sum of the number and the previous number, but the sum of the number and number - 1, which must not be the previous number.

Comment: I have to sum suppose "current number(5) + previous number(5-1)". It will is right. But I am not sure as I am new to python. @MG92

Comment: return statement would terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
rng = range(10)

def sum_of_numbers(current_number):
  sum_ = current_number + (current_number -1)
  // do other logic
  return current_number, sum_

for i in rng:
  current_number, sum_ = sum_of_numbers(i)
  print("current number is "+ str(current_number) + ". And sum of the previ. and curr. number is " + str(sum_))
```

You have to have the function in the loop. Not the for loop in the function. Since, the return statement in the loop would prevent the further iterations of the loop. ie, only one iteration will be done.

OR go like this.

```
rng = range(10)
def sum_of_numbers(x) :
  for i in x :
    b = i + (i-1)

    if i in x :
        b = b
    elif b < 0 : # when number will be negative.
        b = i
    print("current number is"+ str(i) + ". And sum of the previ. and curr. number is " + str(b))

sum_of_numbers(rng)
```

Anyways remember that

> A return statement is used to end the execution of the function call and “returns” the result (value of the expression following the return keyword) to the caller. The statements after the return statements are not executed. If the return statement is without any expression, then the special value None is returned. Note: Return statement can not be used outside the function.

Comment: rng = range(10)
def sum_of_numbers(x) :
    for i in x :
        if b = i + (i-1) :
            return b
        elif b < 0 :
            return i

print(sum_of_numbers(rng))  #what is going wrong in this code. I just modified it.

Comment: condition is wrong. You have written assignment operator. Also, this condition will never be true. `b == i+(i-1)`. Gives NameError.

Comment: You have clearly stated that "Iterate from start number to the end number and print the sum of the current number and previous number." which means that you have to iterate and call a function each time which returns the value/s

Comment: Thankyou that helped